# How to create global secondary index with PocoDynamo?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.servicestack.net/aws-pocodynamo#global-secondary-indexes) page of PocoDynamo for Global Secondary Indexes.

I created the `OrderCostGlobalIndex` class and registered `Order` class as given in the documentation using the following:

```cs
db.RegisterTable<Order>();
db.InitSchema();
```

However, when I run this to create the table in AWS, the table has no indexes. How is the global secondary index created using PocoDynamo and not the AWS Console?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I created using Poco a long while back:

```
using PocoDynamo;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel;

// Define the POCO class for your table
[DynamoDBTable("MyTable")]
public class MyTableItem
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey("MyTableItemId")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("MyTableItemName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexRangeKey("MyTableItemDateIndex")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

// Initialize the DynamoDB client and PocoDynamo context
var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
var context = new PocoDynamo(client);

// Define the properties for the global secondary index
var gsi = new GlobalSecondaryIndex
{
    IndexName = "MyTableItemDateIndex",
    KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
    {
        new KeySchemaElement("MyTableItemId", KeyType.HASH),
        new KeySchemaElement("MyTableItemDateIndex", KeyType.RANGE)
    },
    Projection = new Projection { ProjectionType = ProjectionType.ALL },
    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput { ReadCapacityUnits = 5, WriteCapacityUnits = 5 }
};

// Create the table with the global secondary index
context.CreateTablesIfNotExists<MyTableItem>(
    new CreateTableRequest
    {
        ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput { ReadCapacityUnits = 5, WriteCapacityUnits = 5 },
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes = new List<GlobalSecondaryIndex> { gsi }
    });
```